# How to show the hexvalues of a line of a large file in Unix?

Tags: files, hexidecimal

I am importing data from a large text file into a database and am getting an error on line X of the file. If I look at the line with the less viewer I do not see anything strange, because, most probably, the line has non printable characters. Then I tried to sed the line and check it with a hexdump:

```
sed -n 2540283p 30gb_large_file.fzp | hexdump -C
```

again, nothing, most probably, because sed filtered out all non-printable characters.

Any comments how I could see what's happening on the specific line of a large file in hex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` should not be "[filtering] out all non-printable characters" - you're not telling it to do so. In fact a simple test on a convenient binary file (the FreeBSD kernel) demonstrates that this is not the case - `sed` happily passes non-printable characters.

> Shame on you for publicly accusing poor innocent `sed` of doing something heinously wrong without giving it the benefit of a proper test first -- I'll leave it to your guilty conscience to come up with an appropriate act of contrition!

If `sed` is not giving you any output it's because there's nothing to give -- either that line doesn't exist (maybe the file ends abruptly - Didjya check with `wc -l`? Maybe there's an `EOF` in there somewhere it shouldn't be and your program is aborting when it sees it?).
It's also possible that the line in question consists of just a newline or a `NUL` character (which `sed` should dutifully return, but which wouldn't be of much use to you in a hexdump)...

Comment: An appropriate act being feeding `sed` a steady diet of 1s and 0s.

Comment: After 10 hours of crunching the issue I found the problem. Since the file was huge, the input was compressed. I was decompressing it on the fly, piping it to my program, and importing the data from the stdin. Unfortunatelly, the data was compressed with rar. Even more unfortunatelly, the `unrar p` (decompress to stdout) buggily decompressed my data, causing the error. Completely unfortunatelly, `unrar x` decompressed everything without any errors whatsoever (not showing the symbols `unrar p` was generating). What a day.

Comment: @arthur that is a delightfully disgusting situation. Have a free shot of the debugging tequila. (And add one more reason to the "Why I despise `rar` archives" list)